# Wrapping tab order with a div (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I have two forms on my page, and when focus is set to one of the forms, i want the user to only be able to tab through the current form.

heres what the html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('form').each(function() {                                
      obj = jQuery(this);
      obj.find('input:last').keydown(function(e) {                       
        if (e.keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftKey) {                       
          e.preventDefault();                                
          obj.find('input:first').focus();                   
        }
      })                                      
      obj.find('input:first').keydown(function(e) {                      
        if (e.keyCode == 9 && e.shiftKey) {                        
          e.preventDefault();                                
          obj.find('input:last').focus();                    
        }
      })
    })
  })
</script>
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="1" />
    <input id="2" />
  </form>
  <form>
    <input id="3" />
    <input id="4" />
  <form>
</body>
</html>
```

When pressing tab, starting on id 1, the tab order looks like this:

```
1 <tab> 2 <tab> 3 <tab> 4 <tab> 3 <tab> 4 <tab> ...
```

Pressing shift + tab starting on id 2:

```
2 <shift> + <tab> 1 <shift> + <tab> 4 <shift> + <tab> 3 <shift> + <tab> 4 <shift> + <tab> 3 ...
```

What i would like to have happen is, when on id 1:

```
1 <tab> 2 <tab> 1<tab> 2 <tab> ...
```

And backwards:

```
1 <shift> + <tab> 2 <shift> + <tab> 1 ...
```

Any ideas why the tab order wraps on the last form, but not on the first?

Comment: Your last `<form>` should be changed to `</form>`. I doubt that is the problem, but it may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Replace

```
obj.find('input:first').focus();
```

with

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input:first').focus();
```

and replace

```
obj.find('input:last').focus();
```

with

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input:last').focus();
```

The reason it wasn't working is because the value of `obj` is getting changed on the second time that `.each()` runs.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously solved the problem I however had similar issue a while ago and came up with tiny plugin that limits fields that TAB (shift+TAB) affects. I hope it might help someone with similar issue as this seems pretty common.

Simply use it:

```
$(".someGroup").tabGuard();
```

or in your case

```
$($("form")[0]).tabGuard();
$($("form")[1]).tabGuard();
```

and that will make tab iterate over fields inside of one form only, depending which is in focus. This way you can group various groups of fields on a page and the one in focus will keep iterating on TAB or Shift+TAB if that makes sense. Find it here:

http://tomaszegiert.seowebsolutions.com.au/tabguard/index.htm